# Horizontal and vertical separation of Twitter Bootstrap's buttons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

What is causing Twitter Bootstrap's buttons horizontal separation?

[image]

I can't find it in CSS code.

I'm trying to repeat the very same for vertical, but it seems that I'm failing to achieve this:

[image]

How can I add vertical separation between buttons, only if they're stacked vertically (second picture), but avoiding the same (unnecessary in this case), when they're not (first picture)?

**EDIT**: Code used to generate above pictures:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row-fluid">

        <div class="well well-small" id="menu-buttons">

            <div class="pull-left" style="width: 48%">

                <a class="btn btn-small">@ Style ^</a>
                <a class="btn btn-small">@ Language ^</a>

            </div>

            <div class="pull-right text-right" style="width: 48%;">

                <a class="btn btn-small">@ Device</a>
                <a class="btn btn-small">@ Webpage</a>

            </div>

            <div style="clear: both"></div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: It would be easier to answer that if you showed your code. My guess is this is something to do with floats, see from the web inspector whether the "@ Device" and "@ Webpage" buttons have a float value defined.

Comment: wrap those button in a `div` with `inline-block`.  Incase if it is because of float use `clear: both`

Comment: @quinnirill: Sorry, for missing that out. Here's updated question with the code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What I would do is something like this:

```
.btn {
    margin: 2px;
}
.well {
    padding: 7px;
}
```

So I addedd a margin of 2px around each button, and reduced the padding of the container (.well) by 2 pixels. This way your 'full width' style remains unchanged, and the 'narrow' style will now have a 4 pixel spacing between the buttons.

You may want to ad an extra id or something in front of those selectors, to make it only work on your "#menu-buttons"

And an example: http://jsfiddle.net/eHYnQ/

Comment: Man, it seems that your solution ROCKS! Let me do some more checks, but it really looks promising.

Comment: I do not get why bootstrap does not have some class for margin top prepared

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by adding a `margin-bottom` property to your buttons. In the first picture, it's probably a `float: right;` with a `margin-right: 5px;`

Comment: This is first thing, I thought about and it won't work. Adding `margin-bottom` permanently (in both cases) would produce unacceptable additional space between buttons and bottom border of well that surrounds them, in first case (when buttons are not stacked vertically).

Answer (score 2):

It's the `row-fluid` class who causes the horizontal margin.
You can make a `row-fluid` in a `row fluid` to get vertical spacing.
See the [bootstrap - fluidGridSystem](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem) at Fluid nesting..

---

You should also use `span` classes to fix the width

---

Fiddle : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TJUcg/)
Screen :

[image: Screen capture]

Here is my code : 
**Warning** Remove the `<div class="span3" style="background-color:whitesmoke">` for a full screen wide div

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
</head>
<body>
        <div class="span3" style="background-color:whitesmoke">
            <div class="row-fluid">

                <div class="row-fluid">

                    <div class="span6">
                        <button>1</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span6">
                        <button class="pull-right">2</button>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="row-fluid">

                    <div class="span6">
                        <button>3</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span6">
                        <button class="pull-right">4</button>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Comment: I put your code inside mine, with and without surrounding it with `container-fluid`, and in both cases I see some strange results -- each button is in a separate row. Maybe I'm missing something? This is completely not, what I'm looking for. Results are completely different than presented on my pictures. Do you have some fiddle to present, that your solution actually works.

Comment: Ah, I see. Your soultion works perfect on wide-screen resolutions. But fails completely on mobile ones.

Comment: remove the div span3 for mobile use

Comment: Accept the anser so ;)

Comment: Sorry, but PeterVR's solution works much better, and I decided to use his. Beside, your solution (after removing `div span3`) works fine in desktop browser, when it is sized to the very small (mobile like) size. But, when the very same solution is compiled as PhoneGap application (or run under Ripple Emulator), it doesn't work again -- I see all four buttons, each in separate line. Don't know, why. Maybe this has something to do with pixel-per-inch density? Anyway, PeterVR's solution works in all condition, so I'm gonna accept his answer, sorry.

Comment: Is this the Bootstrap link you meant? http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem

Answer (score 0):

You can try building on the following:

```
#menu-buttons a:first-child {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

(The selector is overtly specific, you should do something about that)

Comment: This won't work -- see my comment to Amine's answer above. Works fine, when buttons are stacked vertically, but looks ugly (first and second button in each group mis-aligned), when they're not stacked and are all in one line.

Answer (score 0):

Upon checking your code, you have wrapped  button pair inside a div.

So instead of having **%** value change to **px**

```
<div class="pull-left" style="width: 115px; "> <a class="btn btn-small">@ Style ^</a>
 <a class="btn btn-small">@ Language ^</a>

</div>
<div class="pull-right text-right" style="width: 115px;"> <a class="btn btn-small">@ Device</a>
 <a class="btn btn-small">@ Webpage</a>

</div>
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SauLj/266/)

---

**Updates:** As you mentioned in comments about fluid design, here is a ***simple way to do it in HTML `<br/>` tag to get line breaks.***

```
<div class="pull-left" style="width: 38% "> <a class="btn btn-small">@ Style ^</a>
    <br/> <a class="btn btn-small">@ Language ^</a>

</div>
<div class="pull-right text-right" style="width: 38%"> <a class="btn btn-small">@ Device</a>
    <br/> <a class="btn btn-small">@ Webpage</a>

</div>
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SauLj/270/)

Comment: As you may see (classes `container-fluid` and `row-fluid` at top divs) this is a fluid layout, so giving absolute values in pixels is not an option at all. Side comment: I've opened your jsFiddle and see no vertical separation in both buttons groups.

Comment: In both your fiddles (original and updated one) I see buttons in both groups stacked vertically with no separation (space) in between them. Actually, I see them nearly exactly like on my second picture. The same, when I use your code in my project. That's why I'm saying, that this is not working -- no vertical separation between butttons.